# how to update a date with in month for particular table

Tags: sql

```
id      desg     date 

1       hr       2017-01-03
2       hr       2017-02-04
3       fin      2017-09-03
4       hr       2017-03-06
```

i want to update the date is jan and feb months only and desg is hr how

Comment: With that table data, what's the expected result? (Well formatted text here too.)

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: In standard SQL: `where extract(month from date) in (1,2) and desg = 'hr'`

Answer (score 0):

update table tablename x set x.desg= "" where month(date) in (1,2)

Comment: @jevva123: you need to tell us which DBMS you are using (Postgres? Oracle? Something else?)